# Need help in uploading bulk products in magento 1.9.4

Tags: magento-1.9

I am running magento 1.9.4.5.

This is the process i run to import my products

I exported the csv which got generated from the products already uploaded
- I modified the same csv and saved it as different name (saved in utf-8 format)

- Uploaded the csv to var/import
- Uploaded the images to media/catalog/product folder
- Here is my csv file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gy1WijbkVpoIk69XcJLw4mgpB6jmabdxtps0cE2-KwE/edit?usp=sharing
- Error is 
  Image does not exist.

Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"

Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"

Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"

Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"

Please help me to fix the same.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but maybe you can fill the `type` column for all the lines you have in your file.

Comment: not working like the way you told